# Accordion Menu - java script not allowing on click drop down

Tags: javascript, html, css

i am using css menu maker to create a accordion menu for an internal site (using google sites so it will be created as an app and then embed in the page). i am testing the functionality out and the on click will not drop down in jsfiddle. code samples are below -

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#cssmenu > ul > li > a').click(function() {
  $('#cssmenu li').removeClass('active');
  $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');  
  var checkElement = $(this).next();
  if((checkElement.is('ul')) && (checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
    $(this).closest('li').removeClass('active');
    checkElement.slideUp('normal');
  }
  if((checkElement.is('ul')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
    $('#cssmenu ul ul:visible').slideUp('normal');
    checkElement.slideDown('normal');
  }
  if($(this).closest('li').find('ul').children().length == 0) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false; 
  }  
})
});
```

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:300,400,500,700);

@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,300);
@charset "UTF-8";
/* Base Styles */
#cssmenu,
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu li,
#cssmenu a {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  list-style: none;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  position: relative;
}
#cssmenu {
  width: 250px;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #656659;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
#cssmenu a {
  line-height: 1.3;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:first-child {
  background: #66665e;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#66665e 0%, #45463d 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #66665e), color-stop(100%, #45463d));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#66665e 0%, #45463d 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(#66665e 0%, #45463d 100%);
  border: 1px solid #45463d;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
  border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:first-child > a {
  padding: 15px 10px;
  background: url(https://0271bc0bca811dbbbe95f5d8e946d85a0792229e.googledrive.com/host/0B5W8nbTl37-fflA5c21VZVU1clNvUTQ1a21TN055SUllTkhRTWpkLXAyU1VzVmFjbmtBOXc/pattern.png) top left repeat;
  border: none;
  border-top: 1px solid #818176;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
  border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 1px #000000;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:first-child > a > span {
  padding: 0;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:first-child:hover {
  background: #66665e;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#66665e 0%, #45463d 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #66665e), color-stop(100%, #45463d));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#66665e 0%, #45463d 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(#66665e 0%, #45463d 100%);
}
#cssmenu > ul > li {
  background: #6691c6;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#6691c6 0%, #4477b5 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #6691c6), color-stop(100%, #4477b5));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#6691c6 0%, #4477b5 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(#6691c6 0%, #4477b5 100%);
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover {
  background: #5b89c2;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#5b89c2 0%, #3f6faa 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #5b89c2), color-stop(100%, #3f6faa));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#5b89c2 0%, #3f6faa 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(#5b89c2 0%, #3f6faa 100%);
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  font-size: 14px;
  display: block;
  background: url(https://0271bc0bca811dbbbe95f5d8e946d85a0792229e.googledrive.com/host/0B5W8nbTl37-fflA5c21VZVU1clNvUTQ1a21TN055SUllTkhRTWpkLXAyU1VzVmFjbmtBOXc/pattern.png) top left repeat;
  color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #3d6aa3;
  border-top: none;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 1px #28466b;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a > span {
  display: block;
  padding: 12px 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.active {
  border-bottom: none;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a span {
  background: url(https://0271bc0bca811dbbbe95f5d8e946d85a0792229e.googledrive.com/host/0B5W8nbTl37-fflA5c21VZVU1clNvUTQ1a21TN055SUllTkhRTWpkLXAyU1VzVmFjbmtBOXc/icon_plus.png) 96% center no-repeat;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub.active > a span {
  background: url(https://0271bc0bca811dbbbe95f5d8e946d85a0792229e.googledrive.com/host/0B5W8nbTl37-fflA5c21VZVU1clNvUTQ1a21TN055SUllTkhRTWpkLXAyU1VzVmFjbmtBOXc/icon_minus.png) 96% center no-repeat;
}
/* Sub menu */
#cssmenu ul ul {
  display: none;
  background: #fff;
  border-right: 1px solid #a2a194;
  border-left: 1px solid #a2a194;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li {
  padding: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
  border-top: none;
  background: #f7f7f7;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#f7f7f7 0%, #ececec 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #f7f7f7), color-stop(100%, #ececec));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#f7f7f7 0%, #ececec 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(#f7f7f7 0%, #ececec 100%);
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}
#cssmenu ul ul a {
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 25px;
  display: block;
  color: #676767;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: normal;
}
#cssmenu ul ul a:before {
  content: "»";
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  color: #6691c6;
}
#cssmenu ul ul a:hover {
  color: #6691c6;
}
```

```html
<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
   <li class='active'><a href='https://sites.google.com/a/manpowergroup.com/experis-uk-intranet/?pli=1'><span>Home</span></a></li>
   <li><a href='https://sites.google.com/a/manpowergroup.com/experis-uk-intranet/our-company/continuous-improvement/our-key-verticals'><span>Our Key Verticals</span></a></li>
   <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Management Team</span></a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href='https://sites.google.com/a/manpowergroup.com/experis-uk-intranet/our-company/meet-the-management'><span>Experis Operations Board</span></a></li>
         <li class='last'><a href='https://sites.google.com/a/manpowergroup.com/experis-uk-intranet/our-company/meet-the-management/experis-senior-leadership-team'><span>Experis Senior Leadership Team</span></a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href='https://sites.google.com/a/manpowergroup.com/experis-uk-intranet/our-company/vision-values'><span>Vision and Values</span></a></li>
   <li><a href='https://sites.google.com/a/manpowergroup.com/experis-uk-intranet/our-company/company-structure'><span>Group Structure</span></a></li>
   <li class='has-sub'><a href='https://sites.google.com/a/manpowergroup.com/experis-uk-intranet/our-company/our-brand'><span>Our Brand</span></a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href='https://sites.google.com/a/manpowergroup.com/experis-uk-intranet/our-company/company-structure/presentations'><span>Brand Presentations</span></a></li>
         <li><a href='https://sites.google.com/a/manpowergroup.com/experis-uk-intranet/our-company/our-brand/powerpoint-templates'><span>Document Templates</span></a></li>
         <li class='last'><a href='https://sites.google.com/a/manpowergroup.com/experis-uk-intranet/our-company/our-brand/branded-merchandise'><span>Merchandise</span></a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li class='has-sub'><a href='https://sites.google.com/a/manpowergroup.com/experis-uk-intranet/our-company/thought-leadership'><span>Thought Leadership</span></a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href='https://sites.google.com/a/manpowergroup.com/experis-uk-intranet/our-company/thought-leadership/tech-cities-job-watch-q2-2015'><span>Tech Cities Job</span></a></li>
         <li class='last'><a href='https://sites.google.com/a/manpowergroup.com/experis-uk-intranet/our-company/thought-leadership/meos'><span>MEOS</span></a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li class='has-sub'><a href='https://sites.google.com/a/manpowergroup.com/experis-uk-intranet/our-company/corporate-social-responsibility'><span>Corporate Social Responsibility</span></a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href='https://sites.google.com/a/manpowergroup.com/experis-uk-intranet/our-company/corporate-social-responsibility/charity'><span>Charity</span></a></li>
         <li><a href='https://sites.google.com/a/manpowergroup.com/experis-uk-intranet/our-company/corporate-social-responsibility/environment'><span>Environment</span></a></li>
         <li class='last'><a href='https://sites.google.com/a/manpowergroup.com/experis-uk-intranet/our-company/corporate-social-responsibility/ethics'><span>Ethics</span></a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li class='has-sub last'><a href='#'><span>Continuous Improvement</span></a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href='https://sites.google.com/a/manpowergroup.com/experis-uk-intranet/our-company/continuous-improvement'><span>ISO</span></a></li>
         <li class='last'><a href='https://sites.google.com/a/manpowergroup.com/experis-uk-intranet/our-company/employee-of-the-month'><span>Employeee of the Month (EoM)</span></a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

here is the jsfiddle for the code given here

[Demo code](https://jsfiddle.net/fbj8y4k3/)

Comment: what is the problem in this..? see the jsfiddle is created

Comment: strange, that jsfiddle would not allow the + - dropdowns to work yesterday, the one you have done works now. However i have put this into a Google App and calling the js file from a Google drive and it does not work. link for the live app is - https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbykio5BRGoFzrOT5NOr8gBTJsKMrVYiGqCSeMKlu49vwDoSCi_r/exec

Comment: i am calling the js using this - <html lang=''>
<head>
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="https://0271bc0bca811dbbbe95f5d8e946d85a0792229e.googledrive.com/host/0B5W8nbTl37-fflA5c21VZVU1clNvUTQ1a21TN055SUllTkhRTWpkLXAyU1VzVmFjbmtBOXc/script.js"></script>
</head>

Comment: it might be some mistake for loading live app's js

Comment: how would i work around this?

Comment: actually i am not able to getting it still please can you be clear about the question.?

Comment: if you try to open the app here, https://script.google.com/a/macros/experis.co.uk/s/AKfycbykio5BRGoFzrOT5NOr8gBTJsKMrVYiGqCSeMKlu49vwDoSCi_r/exec, the on click drop downs dont work. The html calls the CSS and the JS from a Google drive and is shared publicly, the CSS calls fine as it formats it but it would appear that the JS wont as the drop down functionality wont work